# PayPal IPN for CC

Tags: api, paypal

When I'm testing payment on my site using paypal account I'm receiving PDT (silent post) and then notification (IPN). But when I'm testing payment using credit card, I'm getting only silent post and no notification from IPN service. Also I can't find any sale transaction where has been used credit card on sandbox.paypal and no notifications in IPN History, but it (transaction) exists on manager.paypal. Also no charges to merchant account. Is it fine? Can anybody tell me how should I check that money transferred successfully and transaction completed when used cc for payment?

Thanks,
Eugene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have PayPal set up to handle your Express Checkout transactions, and a 3rd processor set up to handle your credit card transactions on your test Payflow account which would cause the issue that you are seeing.  As IPN is only set up on the PayPal account, and if your credit cards are not being processed through PayPal you wont get an IPN.  If you can provide one of the transaction id's I can confirm this on my end.

Comment: So if I understood correct, problem is in test account? My pp manager accepted setting https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B04_4mVQHvTWdDhPTE5zdURmclk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Correct.  So the only transactions you are going to get IPN's for are your Express Checkout transactions.  Your credit card transactions are being processed through FDMS, not PayPal.  So you wont get an IPN for these.

Comment: Thank you. But I think it would be very useful to make some fake cc processor on paypal side to give developers an ability to test payment with cc.

Comment: You can test payments with credit cards.  IPN, is a PayPal service, so since your payments are not being processed through your PayPal account but rather a 3rd party you would not get an IPN.  If you are wanting PayPal to process your payments and to send your IPN, you would just need to switch the processon on the account from FDMS to PayPal.

Comment: How can I do this? didn't find this option on manager.pp and on sandbox account. Or there's no such option for test account? Sorry, my English skills are not good yet, and sometimes I cant understand an idea of sentences)

Comment: You can't switch the processor your self on the account, once it has been set up.  You would need to contact PayPal and have it switched.